# Adding Property to another Array of objects from another set of Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have 2 Array of objects and I want to conditionally add one to the other.

```
let aData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    item: "shirt",
    price: "24.99",
    quantity: "1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    item: "pants",
    price: "34.99",
    quantity: "5"
  }
]

let bData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    item_id: 1,
    url: "imagelink.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    item_id: 1,
    url: "image2link.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    item_id: 2,
    url: "image3link.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    item_id: 2,
    url: "image4link.jpg"
  {
]
```

What I would like is to add all of `bData` to `aData` if the bData[i].item_id == aData[i].id

```
let cData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    item: "shirt",
    price: "24.99",
    quantity: "1",
    images: [
      {
        id: 1,
        item_id: 1,
        url: "imagelink.jpg"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        item_id: 1,
        url: "image2link.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   etc...
  }
]
```

I am at a standstill and this is what I've came up with so far

```
let temp = [];
for (i = 0; i < aData.length; i++) {
        let temp2 = [];
        
        temp2.push(aData[i]);
        let tempImages = {};
        for (k = 0; k < bData.length; k++) {
          if (aData[i].id == bData[k].item_id) {
            
            tempImages[k] = bData[k];
          }
        }
        temp2.images = tempImages;
        temp.push(temp2)
      }
```

This is not doing what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather to use `map` and `filter` to do the job in a very clean way.

the code should be:

```
const result = aData.map(a => {
  a.images = bData.filter(b => b.item_id === a.id);
  return a;
})
```

here is a working example with your sample data.

```js
let aData = [{
    id: 1,
    item: "shirt",
    price: "24.99",
    quantity: "1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    item: "pants",
    price: "34.99",
    quantity: "5"
  }
]

let bData = [{
    id: 1,
    item_id: 1,
    url: "imagelink.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    item_id: 1,
    url: "image2link.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    item_id: 2,
    url: "image3link.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    item_id: 2,
    url: "image4link.jpg"
  }
]

const result = aData.map(a => {
  // use Object.assign to avoid changing the reference of aData
  const completeObject = Object.assign({}, a)
  completeObject.images = bData.filter(b => b.item_id === a.id);
  return completeObject;
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
temp = []
for (i = 0; i < aData.length; i++) {
    if (aData[i].id == bData[i].item_id) {
        temp.push(bData[i]);
    }
}

aData = aData.concat(temp);
console.log(aData);
```

Comment: @Brandon Downhour Do let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You could collect all images first by a grouping with `item_id` and map all items with a new property `images`.

This approach need only one iteration for every array.

```js
const
    items = [{ id: 1, item: "shirt", price: "24.99", quantity: "1" }, { id: 2, item: "pants", price: "34.99", quantity: "5" }],
    images = [{ id: 1, item_id: 1, url: "imagelink.jpg" }, { id: 2, item_id: 1, url: "image2link.jpg" }, { id: 3, item_id: 2, url: "image3link.jpg" }, { id: 4, item_id: 2, url: "image4link.jpg" }],
    imagesByItems = images.reduce((r, o) => ((r[o.item_id] ??= []).push(o), r), {}),
    result = items.map(o => ({ ...o, images: imagesByItems[o.id] || [] }));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```